# What kind of mask is required for grouting?

Tags: tile, safety, grout

I finished putting up tiles for a backsplash last night and am getting ready to grout tonight.  I looked at the package and saw `Contains known or probable carcinogens`.  Yikes!

What kind of mask should I pick up on my way home?  A simple dust mask, or a more elaborate respirator?

Comment: Me thinks you'd have to do more than a single grout job to see any ill effects, but then again I'm no cancer expert. Avoid huffing the dry mix, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Usually that warning applies [only in California](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Proposition_65_%281986%29#Warning_label)—most states are not at risk.  :-)

The carcinogen involved is cement dust, specifically its components of tri- and dicalcium silicate, alumina, tricalcium aluminate, and iron oxide.  The [hazard extends to skin, eyes, mouth, and respiration](http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/npg/npgd0521.html).

[image]
To be completely protected, a [moon suit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleanroom_suit) (made of Tyvek in the photo) is in line with the most pessimistic expectations.  However, the practical alternative (and recommended by CDC and [OSHA](https://www.osha.gov/Publications/concrete_manufacturing.html)) is any quarter-mask respirator with an N-95, R, or P filter to arrest fine particles, along with gloves, and enclosed eye protection—and avoiding unnecessary cement contact.

Many workers are skeptical of the carcinogenic property of cement dust:  it is common to see experienced workers taking only minor precautions.  Usually wearing only a mask while handling the powder.  Once it is moistened and and dust is no longer a factor, most don't do anything special.  But it is a strong caustic alkalai, so do take care not to get it inside or on you for an extended time.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends how sensitive you are to things.  I can see wearing a respirator while mixing the grout because there could be potentially a lot of dust coming up.  But putting it on is akin to painting.  There are some fumes but this isn't harsh stuff.

Honestly I mix most of my smaller grout jobs in big plastic Hawaiian punch jugs cut 3/4 and I mix in the grout slowly into 2-3 inches of water and keep stirring slowly.   I don't even bust out the electrical paddle until most or all of my grout is in the jug and there is hardly a mess or dust.

I don't wear anything but my advice would to wear whatever you would if you were painting (with rollers).  Same toxicity levels.